# Imagedestroy does not to free memory

Tags: php, image-processing

I run a loop that contains a script that identifies white backgrounds in images and then copies a cropped version of the image without that white bacground. In the end of the loop I use imagedestroy to free the memory but the script nonetheless exceed memory limit (>256mb).
How can this be?

Code inside loop:

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgSrc);

/* Script for identifying whitespace */

//create new image
$newimg = imagecreatetruecolor(
            imagesx($img)-($wsLeft+$wsRight), imagesy($img)-($wsTop+$wsBottom));

//get new width and height
$width = imagesx($newimg);
$height = imagesy($newimg);

//free memory
imagedestroy($newimg);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Comment: PHP is garbage collected - just because you destroy a variable in your code does not mean the memory is instantly freed. [Read this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php) for more info. Doing `$img = $newimg = NULL;` might help.

Comment: I'm not sure this is true. Imagedestroy() should free the memory immediately (as I understand it, this is the point of the function). I'm guessing that you're exceeding the memory limit during a single iteration of the loop or that there is another spot that memory is being attributed in each loop. Can you post the full loop?

Comment: You may have **miscalculated** the variables $wsLeft,$wsRight,$wsTop,$wsBottom resulting in creating bigger image rather than smaller image. I'm just assuming, it's better if you post the entire code so we can understand your script correctly

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Problems with Memory (creating hundreds of Images in a Loop). Try to put as much you can in functions. For any reason PHP handles Image-Resources different in functions.

```
<?php
$newimg = imagecreatefromjpeg2($imgSrc,$wsLeft,$wsRight,$wsTop,$wsBottom);

function imagecreatefromjpeg2($imgSrc,$wsLeft,$wsRight,$wsTop,$wsBottom){
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgSrc);
    $newimg = imagecreatetruecolor(
    imagesx($img)-($wsLeft+$wsRight), imagesy($img)-($wsTop+$wsBottom));


        imagedestroy($img);
        return $newimg
}
$width = imagesx($newimg);
$height = imagesy($newimg); 
 ?>
```